# How can I clear the log in the DLT-Viewer?

Tags: logging, dlt, dlt-daemon

I want to clear the dlt log in the DLT-Viewer. But I can not find the buttons to clear the such many logs.

How can I clear the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: DLT Viewer - Clear button]

On top left part of the window is a button in form of a brush that will help you clear the logs from the current view.

This will clear the screen, but in the case this button was pressed accidentally it still will be possible to restore the logs, they can be found under `%LOCALAPPDATA%/dlt-viewer/cache` directory.